# Django - Get childs of child objects?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

If I have a structure with **one level** of child objects I can easily get them through `parent.child_set.all()` However I want to get **childs of childs** as objects from database. Must I really tinker away with recursion or is there some simpler django queryset method to get all child-related objects?

Comment: FWIW, you're better off using something like django-mptt or django-treebeard for hierarchical relationships than rolling your own. There's been a *ton* of time, energy and thought devoted to these packages already as well as contributions from the community. You simply won't develop anything better on your own in a vacuum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something in "other directions" should work, so it would be e.g.:

```
SecondChild.objects.filter(first_child__parent=some_parent)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use `filter` rather than using `child_set`. Try to filter on the Model with the `foreign key` attribute.